# Visual Studio macro (-D) from command output

Tags: visual-studio, preprocessor, environment-variables

I'm trying to get the output of `git describe` into my build as a preprocessor define, to use in versioning modules. Unfortunately, it's being a bit contrary (not sure where the issue is).

I had a pre-build event like:

```
 for /f "delims=" %a in ('git describe') do set GITID=%a
```

which works from the command prompt, but returned code 255 in the build (which caused an error). So I changed it to:

```
git describe > buildprops_gitid.txt
set /p GITID= < buildprops_gitid.txt
```

which again, works in command prompt (and doesn't error during build). The file is created with the correct value.

In the preprocessor settings, I then have:

```
BUILD_TARGETFILE=$(TargetFileName)
BUILD_GITID=$(GITID)
```

The former works fine, putting the target filename into the file as expected. The latter doesn't work, instead putting an empty string. I suspect this is related to the env var being lost somewhere along the way.

Is there a way to get the output of CLI programs and use that as variables (`$(var)`) within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

the workaround i found for this was to generate an include file in a pre-build event.
something like the following version.bat script:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('call git describe --always') DO echo #define VCSVERSION "%%i" > vcsversion.h
```

and then add `#include "vcsversion.h"` in the code.

this is basically the solution i suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057237)